# lambda function is not being updated with cloudformation and pipeline in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, continuous-integration, aws-cloudformation, pipeline

I'm trying to build a pipeline to automate a lambda function deployment on AWS.
I created a pipeline, a codebuild and needed IAM roles and integrated them with cloudformation.

here's my buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 14
    commands:
      - echo "Installing from package.json"
      # - npm install
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Build on `date`"
      # - npm run test
  post_build:
    commands:
      - zip -r lambda.zip index.js template.yml
      - aws s3api put-object --bucket github-lambda-demo --key lambda.zip --body lambda.zip


artifacts:
  files:
    - template.yml
  discard-paths: yes
```

And this is my cloudformation template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Template for Lambda Sample.
Resources:
  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName:
        Fn::Sub: lambda-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
              - lambda.amazonaws.com
        Version: 2012-10-17
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaExecute
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: github-lambda-demo
        S3Key: lambda.zip
      Description: demo for lambda deployment
      FunctionName: github-lambda-demo
      Handler: index.handler
      PackageType: Zip
      # Layers: 
      #   - String
      MemorySize: 256
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - LambdaRole
          - Arn
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Timeout: 300
```

All the steps are done quite right with no errors in codePipeline but my lambda function source is not being update as it should be.

Any help?!

Comment: "not being update as it should be" - its not clear? What exactly it should be? What is now, and what do you expect to happen? Any errors?

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior for [Lambda Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html) in cloudformation, Straight from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html):

> Changes to a deployment package in Amazon S3 are not detected
> automatically during stack updates. To update the function code,
> change the object key or version in the template.

So, typically two options:

**First option using versioned S3 Bucket**:

- Enable versioning of S3 bucket where artifact is stored.
- [put-object](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html) cli you have used will return the version of the object.
- Store the [version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html#cfn-lambda-function-code-s3objectversion) in ssm parm or use a custom cloud formation resource to get latest version of an s3 object in cloudformation.

**Second option using ssm parameter**

- Suffix artifact name with a version (or even the git sha) before writing to S3.
- Store the version in an SSM parameter in build process itself.
- Grab the version from SSM parameter in cloudformation.

Comment: Awesome, can you also share a piece of code for the template with object versioning enabled?! or is it something I specify with UI when creating the Pipeline? because in buildspec I can't get return of the command and pass it to template.yml.

Comment: @HosseinHeydari I didn't realize that your CF is running in codepipeline. its not that striaghtforward. When i used first option, i used a custom resource in cloudformation to fetch the latest version of s3 object,(used aws cdk makes it lot easier), may be storing the version in ssm is the way to go?

Comment: I used docker registry to fixed it. thanks for the answers.